# How to generate a region with a finite width/height on say $ y $-direction, but infinite on $ x $-direction?

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

I want to use such a region as an `Epilog` in other figures. I have tried with `HalfPlane`, thinking `RegionIntersection` might work.

```
r1 = HalfPlane[{{0, -.5}, {1, -.5}}, {0, 1}];
r2 = HalfPlane[{{0, .5}, {1, .5}}, {0, -1}];
Region[RegionIntersection[r1, r2]]
```

But it is not a graphics primitive so that it can not be used as an `Epilog`.

Comment: Instead of using `Epilog` use `Show` to combine the figures.